# Reverse Engineering an Encryption Algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, encryption, text, encoding

This is a common question I know, but this question is not regarding a standard encryption algorithm.

I am, as a "fun" venture, attempting to figure out how a text string is encrypted/transformed.

For example,

The string  "aaa" (without quotes) becomes "516E12" (without quotes)
and "bbb" (again without quotes) become "52BF3C".

Now I know that the new string is Hex so I have split the chars into groups:

```
51  6E  12
```

I also know that the first char in the string is the ASCII value for the char in hex minus 10.

```
a = 61
61 - 10 = 51
```

But then I get stumped on how the remaining chars are converted/transformed.

I don't necessarily want the answer given to me, but if someone could point me in a direction I would be very grateful.

EDIT:
I was asked for more information, unfortunatly, all i have is the ability to input a string and get the result.

So i input "aaa" and got the above string and also the following results.
input - output:

- "bbb" is "52BF3C"
- "ccc" is "53CFBC"
- "abc" is "516DC6"

As you see, the first char is always the ASCII HEX value minus 10.

You ask for more info, but do not provide the info you would need.

Comment: With so little information it is impossible to answer.

Comment: what kind of data do you have?

Comment: With this limited information, there are an infinite number of possible transformation algorithms.

Comment: a glance at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table will show your problem as stated is impossible to solve.

Comment: Im not sure what more info i can offer. I input the string, and the result come out. I have found a starting point but dont know where to go, if you could tell me what you would need, i can go looking for that info.   The examples provided are real-life input and output. and i came to the conclusion of the it being hex based on just this info.

Comment: @EricJ. could you specify what you would like to see in the question that is not there?

Comment: `all i have is the ability to input a string and get the result` it this place available online?

Comment: Would be interesting to see aaa vs aab vs aba

Comment: @NiklasB. the outcome of those are: aaa = 516E12,
aab = 516E11,
aba = 516DC4. Was interested to see that b became a value lower than a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll require a bit more information than just a value and the encrypted value (btw.: where's the key). In general you'll have to decompile and analyze the code. Or atleast that's the usual way of doing this task. Good luck with just this little info. Encryption-algorithms are designed for one purpose: to prevent conclusions from the encrypted string to the value and vice versa without using the exact algorithm, so it's technically impossible to apply reverse engineering to this little information.